# Edit pinned sites

Tags: bug, android-app, communities-list

When I attempt to edit pinned sites in the Android app, I can only view one site name at a time on my screen. There is a ridiculous amount of white space between them in the list. Also when I drag and drop to rearrange the ordering, the scroll speed is so fast that I am almost instantly at either the top or bottom of the list and have absolutely no opportunity to drop the placard where I want it.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: VS425PP

  - OS Version: 5.1.1 (161331805d4f5)

[image]

Comment: Broken for a long time, no hint of response from the team (actually, there's no team for the android app).